How to deal with an older toddler who refuses to eat anything but cheerios?
Our three year old is developing another bad habit - he absolutely refuses to eat anything except bowl after bowl of cheerios!
...Well okay it's not that bad - he will sometimes try new foods he is curious about, and he will gladly scarf down yogurt pouches and usually goes for nutrigrain bars too.
But he gets extremely upset if we don't constantly keep a little bowl of cheerios at the ready for him - tugging on our finger to beg us for them (he is speech delayed) and even throwing a fit if we refuse to give him any (and refusing to eat anything else).
He is, for the most part, doing okay on his nutrition, but he used to eat a much more varied number of foods, and I'm worried about him developing a bad habit of only ever filling up on cheerios.
What should we do?

Read them Bread and Jam for Francis (and pay attention yourself).

I have had children in my practice who were highly sensitive to stimuli, also known as highly sensitive children. (They experience sights, sounds, tastes, smells and/or textures more intensely than many.) There was one in particular who was extremely so; so much so that he would only eat pizza, chicken, and spaghetti (no meatballs), and would drink milk or Coke. I can't remember what else he ate; maybe cheesburgers, maybe fruit. He was (and is) intelligent, kind, and fun to be around, but would not bend on the diet; he'd rather go hungry (very quietly and politely so.) He also refused to wear shoes (just sandals) and pants (only long shorts).
His parents put as much nutritious food in front of him as possible, but he was adamant. Bless their hearts, they were the perfect parents for this child. they never got angry with him, never stopped offering other nutritious food, and served him chicken, pizza, and spaghetti. He did take any medicine he needed, and took vitamins. I guess the mouth-feel of encapsulated medicine/vitamins was tolerable.
To say I was worried about this boy, and impressed with his parents would be gross understatements. But I saw him regularly, he was immunized like everyone else, and he stayed healthy. He did well in college, got married in shorts and sandals, and has kids of his own now.
If your child will eat other things but needs a small bowl of cheerios to be content, let him do so. Try to find other things with the same mouth feel as cheerios, with mild flavors, that are a bit more nutritious. You can also make the "nutrigrain" bars yourself (with input from a dietitian if need be) using the most nutritious ingredients you can, e.g. adding nut and legume flours, and honey (no sugar), bits of different fruits, etc. He clearly likes yogurt, so use it to your advantage; it's a healthful food. You can increase the nutritional value of yogurt by adding powdered milk or pasteurized egg whites to it. Try smoothies with a yogurt base; smoothies can contain veggies and nuts very well and remain creamy and tasty when processed with a powerful blender. If it's the feel of yogurt he enjoys, you have lots of options.
His doctor should be following him a bit more closely that the average kid. Make sure he takes vitamins, and work with a dietitian recommended by your doctor. Keep offering him other foods, but not to the point of your or his frustration. Praise him when he tries them (it really might be a big deal to him!). I think this will be ok, but this is something you need to work out between your health care provider and yourselves. Good luck!

Three years is the age where a child learns the rules of behavior (saying hello, washing hands, going to toilets, etc.) and some basic discipline (or, alternatively, they protest against the rules imposed by their parents/caretakers.) One could try finding a compromise by asking the child to try/eat certain amount of food offered before acceding to their demand to eat cheerios. One could also restrict cheerios only to certain meals - e.g., only at lunchtime, but not for dinner or whatever is more suitable/workable for the family.
For good or for bad, parents hold the ultimate power over what happens - one one extreme they could refuse to accede to the child's demands - surely they would eat what is offered to them when hungry. On the other extreme parents may let the child have their way. Striking the balance between these is every parent's (or couple's) personal decision.
Disclaimer:  the above is meant as suggestions/point-of-view. It should not be viewed as an expert opinion.

This is probably just a phase and you need to let it play out
You stated that your toddler had just started doing this behavior, so it doesn't seem like something that's been going on for a while nor does it seem like it's creating health issues.
Both of our children (currently 5 and 7) have gotten themselves locked onto foods where they didn't really want to eat anything else for periods of time. My wife and I took the stance of evaluating things from how nutritionally complete things were and only impose more stringent measures when it was causing issues either for the kids' health or their behavior.
To give a couple of examples of when we would start being more strict:

Kids are complaining about being hungry at bedtime because they wouldn't eat what was served at dinner.

This happened a lot when our kids were younger (especially around 3) and does still happen occasionally. In general, we deal with this by giving them a peanut butter spoon to fill them up and send them back to bed (we don't want to set a precedent that the kitchen is always putting out cooked food for them).

Kids only want to eat things with no or negligible nutritional value.

We pretty much go through this issue twice a year with our youngest. He gets a haul of candy around both Easter and Halloween and if left unsupervised will eat only that. In this situation, we set some expectations for him about when he can have a candy and try and keep them in a spot where we hand them out to him (this is getting a lot harder, but his self-control is getting better as well). So we might get him to agree to one piece of candy per day after school or something. This seems to work very well for him as it sets an expectation for him that he can rely on.

Potty problems.

Even at 5, we are still having potty problems with my son. Part of the reason for this is that it can be hard for us to get him to regular eat enough fiber in his diet so that he doesn't struggle with hard stools and constipation (he absolutely loves eating slices of salami). Frankly, we've tried everything and haven't come to a solution that fully solves this problem. Right now, we've discussed good fiber content foods that he has said he likes and doubled down on making those as readily available as we possible can for him.

Notably, you don't seem to be dealing with any of those issues that I described above. I won't say that you never will, but I think you need to give some latitude for your son to have this thing. Between cheerios, yogurt pouches, and nutrigrain bars it sounds like:

He's getting a good mix of carbohydrates (cheerios, nutrigrain bars) fat (yogurt), and protein (yogurt) to keep him full at bedtime.
None of the things he's eating lack nutritional value. Maybe add some milk in the bowl for some calcium and extra protein.
From the list you've provided, I imagine your son's pretty regular as both the cheerios and nutrigrain bars are decent sources of fiber.

I recommend you let it ride for now. Make dinner as normal, give a small sampling for him but just be ready to trade him for a bowl of cheerios.

He does love drinking his milk - so we have that going for us at least. Even if he doesn't like the milk in his cereal as much.

Be the parent.  A 3yo should not be in a position to demand or refuse anything.
Part of growing is knowing and obeying the rules.  Parents decide what kids eat.  The kid might have a choice between options given by the parent, but the parent should be controlling the available options.
If the parent says to eat the meat and vegetables, the child should eat them.  Otherwise, it's disobedience and you discipline them accordingly.  If you're adverse to disciplining them, you could use the cheerios as a bribe or treat.  The child can have them, but only after they eat the meal in front of them.
If you can't manage whether or not your kid gets cheerios now, you're gonna have a hell of a time as they grow and really start questioning who's the boss.

The style of parenting you advocate is known as authoritarian parenting and has been shown, of the three major styles of parenting, to be the most damaging to children, leading to the most damaged adults. If you don't have anything more helpful to offer than this nonsense, maybe best in the future to keep scrolling until you find a question you actually have something positive to say. Thanks!

The way this kind of parenting is implemented makes all the difference in the world. Being the parent and firmly guiding kids isn't bad.  I know lots of people raised this way - most of the kids in my generation in my part of the country - and the vast majority of them are very well-rounded, excellent parents themselves, and highly successful. Young kids today, and many young adults, have been babied to the point they don't respect authority, don't want to do real work, and can barely deal with any kind of conflict.  Now the "in" thing is to get therapy for all of their "feelings."  No thanks.

I guess "excellence" is that behavior you hold valuable. I don't find this kind of parenting remotely excellent, and if you read about authoritarian parenting in the literature, you'll see for yourself the kind of people that most often emerge from this. Success is subjective. Your blanket condemnation of, and disdain for, generations following yours is a good example of the result. What defines "real work?" Is being a physician "real work"? How about a nurse? A lawyer? Odds are if you are my age, the people you condemn are the ones you rely on.

Well, yes... the generations following mine are a good example of what happens when you're raised without discipline or respect for authority.  I didn't say "all", I said "many", and anyone with a shred of realistic honesty can see exactly what I'm talking about. I've read articles about "authoritarian" parenting... studies about this and that... and they all dealt with extremes.  Rules and discipline without grace, compassion and love.  Of course that would be bad, but not all rule-based upbringing is delivered in the same way.  Many people do it well and, sure, I consider them successful.
